# React Context doesn't show value in Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to pass value from Context Provider to Consumer, but it shows nothing.

I've watched many questions on StackOverflow about React Context not working, but I haven't found anything that could help me. I use Consumer inside Provider, I tried to wrap Provider in div (it helped someone, but not me), ContextTypes are not the case, since it's a legacy doc, no mistakes about wrong import-export, no spellchecking mistakes, no console mistakes regarding context or passively affecting context. I did everything like in context tutorial video, adapting to my project.

I have a 'productTemplate' in **data.js** that I need to pass:

```js
export const productTemplate = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Samsung Galaxy S10",
    company: "Samsung",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium harum ipsam maiores excepturi, enim quae ex consectetur magnam quo temporibus error, vel iure eveniet id quas expedita cum cupiditate autem!",
    imageSrc: "samsung-galaxy-s10-1.webp",
    imageWidth: 200,
    imageHeight: 200,
    price: 300,
    isInCart: false,
    amountInCart: 0
  }
];
```

I have separate file for context - **context.js**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { products, productTemplate } from './data'; // <-- imported 'productTemplate' correctly

const Context = React.createContext();

class ContextProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      productTemplate: productTemplate  // <-- I need to pass it
    };

    this.setProducts = this.setProducts.bind(this);
    this.getItem = this.getItem.bind(this);
    this.onDetail = this.onDetail.bind(this);
  }

  // Don't mind next 4 methods, they're not related to 'productTemplate'

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setProducts();
  }

  setProducts() {
    let tempProducts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
    this.setState(() => {
      return {products: tempProducts}
    })
  }

  getItem(id) {
    const product = this.state.products.find(item => item.id === id);
    return product;
  }

  onDetail(id) {
    const product = this.getItem();
    this.setState(() => {
      return { detailProduct: product }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ 
        ...this.state,                 // <-- passed this.state in value
        setProducts: this.setProducts,
        getItem: this.getItem,
        onDetail: this.onDetail
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const ContextConsumer = Context.Consumer;

export { ContextProvider, ContextConsumer };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The whole App is wrapped in Provider in **index.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { ContextProvider } from './components/context';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContextProvider>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </ContextProvider>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In **ProductPage.js** I'm testing context on 'title' property, but it shows nothing:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyledDivProductPage, StyledNavBreadcrumbs } from '../styles';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {  ContextConsumer } from '../context';

export default class ProductPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ContextConsumer>
        {value => {
          const { id, title, company, description, imageSrc, price, isInCart, amountInCart } = value.productTemplate;
        
          return (
            <StyledDivProductPage>
              <StyledNavBreadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb" className="align-self-start">
                <ol className="breadcrumb">
                  <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                  <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/mobile_phones">Mobile Phones</Link></li>
                  <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{title}</li> {/*<-- here should be title value, but it shows nothing */}
                </ol>
              </StyledNavBreadcrumbs>
            </StyledDivProductPage>
          )
        }}
      </ContextConsumer>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyIRX.jpg)

[markup in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4EvK.jpg)

I understand, it may be a childish mistake, but it's only my second project on React. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `productTemplate` is an array of values (not an object). In the future, when debugging, I would recommend logging the entire `value` from context (rather than using it right away). For example, right before `return <StyledDivProductPage ...` in `ProductPage` add a `console.log(value)`.

Doing so shows that `productTemplate` is an array so accessing `productTemplate.title` will be `undefined` (which is why nothing is rendered).

This can be fixed by accessing the first item:

```
const { id, title, ... } = value.productTemplate[0]; // access the first element
```

Or update the initial value in state, for example:

```
const productTemplate = { ... } // instead of [{ ... }]
```